# Using enum correctly or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, enums

I'm trying to set up some database tables and create some model classes for the subject of Teacher, Student, Courses, Semester. This is for a MVC3 Web App. If I have a userprofile entity and model class. Would it work if I created a classification enum in the userprofile modelclass and that enum would be either Teacher or Student. Idk If this could work. I don't really know how I can do this b/c I'm going to need the courses that the student is enrolled in and for a teacher, I would need the courses that he/she is teaching and taught. Any advice would be much appreciated.

So for example maybe something like this in the userprofile class:

```
    class UserProfile {

         public Guid UserID { get; set; }
         public string fname { get; set; }
         public string lname { get; set; }
         public Classification classification { get; set; }

     }

    public enum Classification {

        Student, Teacher
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design looks good to me.

You could also use a boolean variable, for instance `UserIsPatient` or `UserIsTeacher`, but by using an enumeration you've created something that can be easily expanded if your requirements change later - for instance, if you wanted to add student teachers, interns, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think what i'm confused on is how the relationships would work. How would I relate my teacher and student entity to the userprofile entity. Right now my group member has the student and teacher entities inheriting the userprofile but we getting all kinds of errors when we do that. Would the relation be pointed to classification or just the userid?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  "Student" and "Teacher" are members of an enumeration, and your UserProfile class has a field to designate whether the UserProfile object refers to a teacher or a student.  As with any field that refers to an enumeration, UserProfile.classification is in fact storing an integer value - in this case, 0 for a student, and 1 for a teacher.  UserProfile.classification is a ForeignKey to Classifications, while UserProfile.UserID is a primary key in your user profiles table.

Comment: Well it's cool cause what I did was I went in the dbml and when into the properties of the classification attribute and I changed the type to global::SolutionName.Models.Enum.Classification...Now I don't have to store integers, the dbml will bring it down as a Classification Enum and try and match Teacher or Student

Answer (score 5):

Your situation is tailor-made for derived type.

`UserProfile` should be abstract, with two concrete types called `Teacher` and `Student`.
These inherited types can then each have different properties.